# How can i read data from Excel sheet in Node JS?

Tags: node.js, excel, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to retrieve data from Excel sheet in node js. Actually i want to do same function retrieving from AWS-S3 object in AWS Lambda(Node JS), but now i am trying to do same thing in local machine.Can you help me either both or single(In Local machine or AWS Lambda).

Comment: You can check the solution to this problem at -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/50850942/1957498

Answer (score 4):

try below 
fist install `xlsx` package

```
npm i xlsx --save
```

use below code snippet

```
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

var workbook = XLSX.readFile('./assets/yourfile.xlsx');// ./assets is where your relative path directory where excel file is, if your excuting js file and excel file in same directory just igore that part
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames; // SheetNames is an ordered list of the sheets in the workbook
data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[0]]); //if you have multiple sheets

for(var key in data){
    console.log(data[key]['yourColumn']);
}
```

more information please refer the documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Comment: Please Can you explain about "./assets " and SheetNames. Thank you in Advance.

Comment: added some comments which will help you

Comment: Is this paid package ??